# aws private instance cannot resolve hostname (VPC with NAT instance)

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

Please note that this question is different than [this one here](https://serverfault.com/questions/675420/cant-connect-aws-vpc-private-instance-to-internet-through-nat) where they used a standard AMI vs NAT AMI (in my case). Also in my case private instance can access Internet via ipaddress but not via hostname resolution.

Here's my setup:

- Non-default VPC with 1 public subnet & 1 private subnet.
- NAT instance on the public subnet with an elastic IP. Used Amazon Community NAT AMI: amzn-ami-vpc-nat-hvm-2017.09.1.20180108-x86_64-ebs ami-d4a883b1. Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1.20180108 x86_64 VPC NAT HVM EBS
- Security group as per [NAT Security Group documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_NAT_Instance.html) attached to NAT instance above
- Private instance (on private subnet) can reach Internet via NAT instance as long as it uses ip address. For example: `curl http://74.125.135.99/` works but `curl http://www.google.com` doesn't work

Private instance:

```
$cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search us-east-2.compute.internal

$ curl http://74.125.135.99/
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>

$ curl http://www.google.com/
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: www.google.com
```

NAT instance:

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search us-east-2.compute.internal
options timeout:2 attempts:5
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

UPDATE: Following DNS settings are on my VPC:

```
DNS resolution: yes
DNS hostnames: yes
```

Answer (score 4):

DNS resolution in a VPC does not depend on the NAT device, whether it's a NAT instance or NAT Gateway, and because of the way it's implemented, it is very difficult if not impossible to break DNS through misconfiguration of the network, because the traffic has no need to be allowed via security groups and Network ACLs.

If it isn't working, that suggests it's not turned on.

Ensure that `enableDnsSupport` is set to `true`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support

You'll probably want to activate `enableDnsHostnames` while you're there.  It does not make your instances "public," despite the fact that the documented description implies that it does.

There is rarely a case for not enabling either of these options.

Comment: On my VPC the following is set.  Is this what you are referring to?

DNS resolution: yes
DNS hostnames: yes

Comment: Yes... but I just noticed `nameserver 127.0.0.1` on your instance.  Any idea how that got that way?  It should be the same as the NAT machine.  They should all be the same, it should be the base address of your VPC + 2 (e.g. 10.0.0.0/x >> 10.0.0.2).

Comment: No idea how it was set - it was set automatically. I rebooted and the values stayed the same.

Comment: Check your [DHCP Options Sets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html).

Comment: Here's what I have for DHCP option set on the VPC:
`domain-name = us-east-2.compute.internal`
`domain-name-servers = AmazonProvidedDNS`

Comment: Found the problem. The issue was I had dnsmasq enabled and was interfering with DNS lookups. Thank you @michael-sqlbot for your help.

Comment: I'm glad you found it, @mpprdev.  If for some reason you wanted to use dnsmasq, it should work if you configure it to use 169.254.169.253 as its upstream server.  That's a special address, functionally equivalent to the x.x.x.2 address for the DNS resolver in your VPC, but portable across different VPCs so it's safe to hard-code.

Comment: Thank you @michael-sqlbot for the 169.254.169.253 tip. Upvoted.

Comment: Note: Older operating system like Windows Server 2008 won't allow DNS servers in the 169.254.x.x network. @Michael-sqlbot tip is a good one and I use that instead of the VPC  Base + 2 address in my AMIs so that they are portable across VPCs.