# NAT in Amazon AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, iptables, amazon-web-services, nat

I am trying to configure NAT in Amazon AWS.

So I have two EC2 with private IPs: **10.0.0.49** and **10.0.0.48**. (**10.0.0.0/24** network)
Nodes in one VPC. I can ping 10.0.0.49 from 10.0.0.48.

Elastic IP **52.88.240.171** pointed to 10.0.0.49.

As I understand I cant point Elastic IP directly to node. Thus I am trying such manual https://serverfault.com/a/568478/192282

On 10.0.0.49:

```
sudo sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 net.ipv4.conf.eth0.send_redirects=0
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

sudo iptables -L -n -v -x -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 457 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 6 packets, 457 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 32 packets, 2732 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
      32     2732 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      eth0    10.0.0.0/24          0.0.0.0/0           
[root@ip-10-0-0-49 ~]#
```

And on 10.0.0.48:

```
sudo route del default
sudo route add default gw 10.0.0.49

sudo route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.0.0.49       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
169.254.169.254 0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
```

In "Security Groups" of Amazon AWS console is enabled all Inbound and Outbound traffic for each EC2.

But I still have no access to Internet on 10.0.0.48 (node w/o Elastic IP).
Maybe I missed smth in aws console? What can be wrong?

**UPD.** resolv.conf for each EC2 host:

```
[root@ip-10-0-0-49 ~]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search us-west-2.compute.internal
nameserver 10.0.0.2

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-48 ~]$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search us-west-2.compute.internal
nameserver 10.0.0.2
```

Comment: can you post what 2 boxes contains in /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: @ostendali see UPD section in main question.

Comment: just out of curiosity, have you reviewed your configuration following this guide her: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Scenario3.html

Comment: Do you have source/dest check disabled on your NAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was problem with "source/dest check" in AWS console. Thanks you, @matt-houser!

[image]